# MVC ASP Insertar en dos tablas en una vista

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Tengo dos Clases Persona y Beneficiarios(Poliza de Vida ) , en la vista necesito crear el cliente y tener la opcion de ingresar beneficiarios uno o varios  .En la clase persona cree la relacion vitual con la clase beneficiario(Icoleccion) . Pero al momento de generar la vista los beneficiarios salen con un dropdown y lo que requiero es que pueda insertar en la vista , les muestro un ejemplo del documento fisico que se requiere autormatizar:[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufvlw.png)[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxmqB.png)[image: mv[![][3]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOTQZ.png)

Comment: Por default los templates de MVC te generan los List de las propiedades como dropdown, si requieres crear una tabla que se vaya llenando conforme vas metiendo los datos entonces creo que al menos yo lo haria con una vista parcial o generando la tabla con js/jquery

Comment: Intente generar una vista parcial de la tabla y al insertar un registro me da error por que no he insertado en la princial